# How to test if href value is a relative value with selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I want to test if the value in my href attributes in my a tags are relative paths using Selenium.

This is my HTML:

```
<a href="/about/somepage/">my page</a>
```

I use selenium to select the a tag:

```
string hrefValue = _chromeDriver.FindElement(By.TagName("a")).GetAttribute("href");
```

This will return "http://mydomain/about/somepage/" even if the part "http://mydomain" is not in the HTML.

If I use `GetAttribute("pathname")` it will give what I want, however the `GetAttribute("pathname")` will only give the value `"/about/somepage/"` EVEN if the HTML looks like this:

```
<a href="http://myDomain/about/somepage/">my page</a>
```

So, how can I test if the actual value of the `href` attribute is relative or not to my website?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to look for the A tag but also examine its href attribute and see if it starts with "http".

```
Console.WriteLine(driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(a[href^='http'])).Any());
```

If this prints False then it's relative.

Answer (score 2):

First, get all the links whose **href** start with **http**. Since, links may be both absolute or relative and you don't whether your desired one is starting with **http** so, an extra checking is necessary if list is greater than 1. Here is the code snippet-

```
       List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[href^='http']"));

        if (links.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("relative");
        }else {
            boolean isAbsolute = false;
            for (WebElement link: links ) {
                if(link.getText().equals("Visit 2.com!")){
                    isAbsolute = true;
                    break;
                }

            }

            if (isAbsolute) {
                System.out.println("absolute");
            }else {
                System.out.println("relative");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi. This will not work unfortunately. Your test will allways say that the domain is present. (And there lies the problem)

Comment: i am trying for your solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Java version:**

retrieve `outerHTML` of the element (link) and check whether it contains `http://` in it.

```
    WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.linkText("my page"));

    String href = link.getAttribute("href");
    String outerHtml = link.getAttribute("outerHTML");

    System.out.println("href " + href);
    System.out.println("outerHtml " + outerHtml);

    if(outerHtml.contains("href=\"http://")){
        System.out.println(href + " is absolute path");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(href + " is relative path");
    }
```

Comment: This could easily give you a false positive if *anything* in the outerHTML has http:// in it... even text.

Comment: @JeffC, IMHO, it is not that much difficult to convert. I don't have C# setup to validate.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it should give you everything inside `<a>` and then you can check it :

`string hrefValue = _chromeDriver.FindElement(By.TagName("a")).getAttribute("innerHTML")`

Edit:

try with `outerHTML` instead. It should give the whole thing

Comment: This only gives me "my page". Not the values in the attribute in any way

Comment: I'm quite sure that this will not return `href="/about/somepage/"` as you expect, but text of element